# public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]product pro)

Tags: c#, json

I have this controller which I have Post Method.. but this method doesn't insert the value in database.. I can't resolve this.. need help

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]product pro)
{
        try
        {
            using (project_smartEntities entities = new project_smartEntities())
            {
                entities.products.Add(pro);
                entities.SaveChanges();


                var message = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, pro);
                message.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri + pro.product_id.ToString());
                return message;
            }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
        }
}
```

> Host: localhost:52442 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64;
>   rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0 Accept: application/json
>   Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>   Connection: keep-alive Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1 Content-Type:
>   application/json

I want to insert these values in my product table

> {"product_name":Maria
>   B","barcode":123456789,"expiry_dates":"2022-05-12T00:00:00","unit":"3pc","tax":500.0,"cost":8000.0,"size":"Medium","quantity":2,"category_id":7,"locations":[],"product_category":null,"purchase_line":[],"sales_line":[]}

Comment: First of all, do you get an exception on entities.SaveChanges() ? and if so. What is the error? Lastly, if you debug the application. What value will the "product" have? is it the expected value you described with your json?

Comment: does it give you a BAD_REQUEST response? or just nothing?

Comment: Its give BAD_REQUEST error and doesn't show any exception

Answer (score 0):

You can check if there are any constraints on Product Table in Db if  `entities.SaveChanges();` is failing.

Answer (score 0):

You should refactor to the more recent api abstractions of web api 2

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]product pro) {    
    try {
        using (var entities = new project_smartEntities()) {
            entities.products.Add(pro);
            entities.SaveChanges();
            return CreatedAtRoute(
                routeName: "DefaultApi", 
                routeValues: new { id = pro.product_id, controller = "products" }, //assuming route template "api/{controller}/{id}" other properties
                content: pro);                
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return BadRequest();
    }    
}
```

Since there are no indications of attribute routing the assumption is that you are using the default convention-based route `DefaultApi`

To debug why entity is not saving put a break point in the exception handler and review the cause of the exception.

Comment: Doesn't work.. still gives the same error BAD_REQUEST without any exception

Comment: @RafiaZaheer Put a break point in the catch and checkthe exception `ex`.